# Destringing variables

Tags: stata

I have a data set that has data sorted by months and years. I want to `destring` the month variable so that I can ultimately create one date variable, but as they are all labeled as January, February, etc. how do I `destring` the variable?

Comment: No attempt at code and no data example. Even if you are just confused, you should always be able to supply a little data example to work on.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. That's a job for date functions. All are documented, e.g. via `help datetime`.

`destring` is for numbers that happen to be read as string variables so that typical entries might be `"42"` and `"666"`. Import as string usually arises when the variable includes metadata (e.g. header lines), or non-Stata flags for missings (e.g. `"NA"`), or some other non-numeric characters, often in as few as one observation. Import from MS Excel is a common cause, as spreadsheet users tend to be loose on sprinkling text in numeric data columns.

A variable with values such as `"January"` doesn't qualify. It's in your mind that month names map on to month numbers, but `destring` doesn't share that knowledge.

Date functions have this job:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str8 month float year
"January"  2017
"February" 1942
end

gen mdate = monthly(month + string(year), "MY")

list 

     +-------------------------+
     |    month   year   mdate |
     |-------------------------|
  1. |  January   2017     684 |
  2. | February   1942    -215 |
     +-------------------------+

format mdate %tm

list 

     +--------------------------+
     |    month   year    mdate |
     |--------------------------|
  1. |  January   2017   2017m1 |
  2. | February   1942   1942m2 |
     +--------------------------+
```

(Declaration of interest: original author of `destring`.)

See also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506490/destring-a-time-variable-using-stata).